# Can´t change port with application.yml file, but it works in application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties

In a Spring Boot application, when i change my server port in
application.properties

```
server.port=9001
```

it works perfectly.
But when i try to use application.yml

```
server:
  port : 9001
```

The port stay as 8080.
I use eclipse. What could be the problem ?

Comment: Include either the output of `tree` in your project base directory, or, if `tree` is not available on your system, a screenshot of the Eclipse Package Explorer showing the structure and your `application.yml`.

Comment: Thank you for replay, already solved, in my answer to @rejo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.M1/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml)

> The SpringApplication class will automatically support YAML as an alternative to properties whenever you have the SnakeYAML library on your classpath.

Do you have SnakeYAML in your classpath?

Comment: I don't know for sure what fixed it, but i tried to add dependency of snakeYaml in my pom.xml. It gives me error (related with classpath) when i started the project. I deleted the dependency, rebuild the project again, and now application.yml is working properly and the port is changed. So, is solved. Thank you.